# React+Express+webpack - clear project for starting from scratch

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

I followed some tutorials and I spent too much time on configuring express+react+webpack working together. Have u got any repository/tutorial which is up-to-date that will allow me to start my project from zero?

Comment: try with the 'boilerplate' keyword on Google :)

Comment: All boilerplates are individual, so you should find best matching for you.